# I don't see my plugin in the "Create Page" dialog in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have created my first simple **`Item`** type plugin without any logic:

```sql
procedure render_vue_component (
    p_item   in            apex_plugin.t_item,
    p_plugin in            apex_plugin.t_plugin,
    p_param  in            apex_plugin.t_item_render_param,
    p_result in out nocopy apex_plugin.t_item_render_result
)
is
begin
    -- some logic
end render_vue_component;
```

but when I try to create a page with `Create Page` - `Plugins` I received the message **"There are no plug-ins installed"** in the `Create Page` dialog.

When I go to `Chared Component` - `Plug-ins` I see my plugin in the list:

[image]

Comment: If it is an **item** type plugin, shouldn't it be visible while creating an **item** on the page, not while creating a page itself? You know, I don't expect to see it among Interactive Reports and Forms, but I do expect to see it among Text items and Select List items etc.

Comment: @Littlefoot, yes, I have already changed plugin type and resolved my problem. I am new with Apex and watched an old video about plugin creation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-_F4zE6jE8 , I know that this video from 2012 and Apex version is 4.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you fixed it.